# Python: IDLE does not show South Asian Language Unicode Characters

Tags: python, unicode

When I enter the following code in IDLE:

```
>>> B=u"\u09FF"
>>> print(B)
```

I see the following output:

```
৿
```

I see a box like character when I actually want to see the character(It's a Bengali character BTW). Why does this happen? Does IDLE not support South Asian and other oriental language Unicode Fonts?

I am using v.3.5.1

Comment: This is not a problem with IDLE, but with the font IDLE is using to display its output.

Comment: What character were you looking for? Code point U+09FF is not assigned to anything (Bengali or otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you are getting is the right character for that unicode point, see [this](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf) table to learn more about unicode points for [Bengali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_alphabet) language and their corresponding characters, so if we take an example:

```
>>> print('\u09F8')
৸
>>> print('\u0986')
আ
>>> print('\u09FF')
৿
```

[image]

Comment: This answer nailed it. I was looking for a character which was out of range and did not correspond to any symbol. Thanks @Iron Fist.

Comment: Which site did you find the above illustration?

Comment: @user3002318 .. I linked on my answer to the references...http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf